# rails nested form changes id to decimal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jruby, nested-forms, jrubyonrails

#### Quick problem description

The value of the id in a nested form is rendered as **`10006.0`** instead of **`10006`** (decimal/float instead of an integer) resulting in an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception.

What is causing this behaviour??

#### The code setup

So I followed the [rails-guides tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms) on how to build nested forms.

My 2 models are:

```
class Broker < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :execution_groups, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :execution_groups, 
                                allow_destroy: true, 
                                reject_if: lambda{|att| att['port'].blank?}
end
```

and

```
class ExecutionGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :broker
  validates :port, presence: true, numericality: true
end
```

My form includes (haml snippet) with the `:id` field explicitly rendered for debugging purposes.

```
= form_for( @broker ) do |f|
  ...
  = f.fields_for :execution_groups, include_id: false do |eg_form|
    %tr
      %td=eg_form.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', type: 'text'
      %td=eg_form.text_field :port, class: 'form-control', type: 'number'
      %td
        =eg_form.check_box :_destroy
        =eg_form.text_field :id, class: 'form-control'
```

The value of the id box is rendered  as **`10006.0`** instead of **`10006`** (decimal/float instead of an integer) resulting in an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception when updating, because there's only a record with id *10006*.

#### My current environment

Otherwise fully functioning

- jruby 1.7.19 (1.9.3p551) 2015-01-29 20786bd on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_45-b14 +jit [darwin-x86_64]
- JDBC Oracle Thin Driver, Implementation-Version: 11.2.0.4.0
- Rails 4.0.13
- Boostrap 3 for Layouts

Comment: What is the database type of the id field?

Comment: `ExecutionGroup.columns_hash[:id].type` gives me 'integer'. And on `ExecutionGroup.first.id` on the rails console returns something like 10001. The above behaviour happens only when using nested forms. Any ideas?

Comment: Curious, if you remove the include_id: false and let rails generate the hidden input, is the id in there also a float?

Comment: Yes it is. I've only started to use `include_id: false` _after_ I got the strange errors.

Comment: Hmm, well you could convert it back to an int in your controller, but that's just a workaround. Have you tried on MRI vs jRuby?

Comment: Not yet tried MRI. The app will be warbled and is supposed to run on a tomcat. How would you convert in controller? I'm not directly addressing ExecutionGroup but only Broker. The rest happens through the nested form where, I assume, one has very little control over details.

Comment: In your call to find the record by id cast the id to an int. Should be in your params hash: params[:broker][:execution_groups][][:id] The params should have all of the data that came over from the form.