# Nested form renders decimal instead of fixnum when using Oracle, JRuby

Tags: oracle, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, jruby, jrubyonrails

When using nested forms with **Oracle DB, Rails renders a decimal/float** (e.g. `10010.0`) instead of a fixnum (e.g. `10010`) for all integer fields, including the `id` field, resulting in exceptions when updating. With **SQLite it works** as expected.

*Why does this happen and where do things go wrong??*

---

## The following code demonstrates the issue:

#### Models

```
class Broker < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :execution_groups, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :execution_groups, allow_destroy: true
end

class ExecutionGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :broker
end
```

#### View

```
= form_for( @broker, html: { class: 'form-horizontal'} ) do |f|
  = f.fields_for :execution_groups, include_id: true do |eg_form|
    = eg_form.hidden_field :id
```

#### Result in Browser when using SQLite

```
...
<input id="broker_execution_groups_attributes_0_id"
     name="broker[execution_groups_attributes][0][id]"
     type="hidden" 
    value="10010" />
...
```

This works as expected, the nested model is updated.

#### Result in Browser when using Oracle

```
...
<input id="broker_execution_groups_attributes_1_id"
     name="broker[execution_groups_attributes][1][id]"
     type="hidden" 
    value="10010.0" />
...
```

This crashes with a neat exception:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in BrokersController#update
Couldn't find ExecutionGroup with ID=10010.0 for Broker with ID=10040
```

As to be expected, AR's not finding an ID like **10010.0** because there's only ID **10010** (without the `.0`) available.

---

#### Current Environment

**.ruby-version** (rvm configuration file)

```
jruby-1.7.19
```

**Gemsfile.lock** (excerpt)

```
rails (4.0.13)
  actionmailer (= 4.0.13)
  actionpack (= 4.0.13)
  activerecord (= 4.0.13)
  activesupport (= 4.0.13)
  bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
  railties (= 4.0.13)
  sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
railties (4.0.13)
  actionpack (= 4.0.13)
  activesupport (= 4.0.13)
  rake (>= 0.8.7)
  thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.3.19)
  activerecord (>= 2.2)
activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter (1.3.19)
  activerecord-jdbc-adapter (~> 1.3.19)
  jdbc-sqlite3 (>= 3.7.2, < 3.9)
jdbc-sqlite3 (3.8.11.2)
```

**config/database.yml**

Oracle via JDBC

```
development:
  url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@mydbhost:1522:myschema
  username: myuser
  password: secret
```

SQLite

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
```

Comment: We have already been discussing this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236210/rails-nested-form-changes-id-to-decimal), but without concrete examples and no solution.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Digging deeper into ActiveRecord I found that specifically overwriting the `id_before_type_cast` method for the model does the trick:

```
class ExecutionGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :broker

  def id_before_type_cast
    Integer( self.id ) unless self.id.nil?
  end    
end
```

While this does the trick, the `*_before_type_cast` needs to be defined for any Fixnum column or you'll get the same problem with the values.

## Debugging details:

Stepping into `ActionView::Helpers::Tags::Base.value_before_type_cast(object)` I get the following status:

```
# for both SQLite and Oracle
object.class == ExecutionGroup # -> true
object.respond_to?(method_before_type_cast) # -> true

# SQLite
object.id_before_type_cast # -> {Fixnum} 10010

# Oracle
object.id_before_type_cast # -> {BigDecimal} 10010.0
```

After applying the fix both Oracle and SQLite show the same behaviour.

```
object.id_before_type_cast # -> {Fixnum} 10010
```